# How to add a third factor to the x axis in a lattice bwplot

Tags: r, plot, lattice, boxplot

I am very new to plotting data and I am trying to add a third factor to my bwplot.

My factors are:

- Site with 6 levels (C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5)
- Seasonal Flow with 2 levels (High, Low)
- Land Use with 2 levels (Urban, Rural)

I have no trouble plotting the Site and Seasonal Flow with the script below:

C <- read.csv('Collie 3.csv')

library(lattice)

```
bwplot(TN.TP~ Site| Seasonal.Flow,data=C,main="Collie River TN:TP",ylab="ratio",xlab="Site + Flow regime", horizontal=FALSE)
```

Datalink: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6q8b1svld61pqsr/Collie%203.csv

My problem is that I would like to also include Land Use on the x-axis, where Sites C0 and C1 are Rural and Sites C2, C3, C4, C5 are Urban. 
I have looked at ggplot, but still haven't figured it out. Even just colouring C0 and C1 differently would help.

Comment: Are you using R? If so, tag it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `ggplot2`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = C, aes(x = Site, y = TN.TP, colour = Land.Use)) +
  facet_wrap( ~ Seasonal.Flow, ncol = 1) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_colour_hue("Land use") +
  ggtitle("Collie River TN:TP") +
  ylab("ratio") +
  xlab("Site + Flow regime")
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you for that. Is there a simple was to change the colours of the boxplot? For some reason I get and error with the ggtitle you supplied. Error in ggtitle("Collie River TN:TP") + ylab("ratio") : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator     Thank you once again Sven

Comment: @user2479514 1) You can specify your own colours with `scale_color_manual`. This replaces `scale_color_hue`. For example, you can try `scale_color_manual("Land use", values = c("blue", "red"))`. 2) I forgot a `+` sign at the end of the line preceding the one with `ggtitle`. Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `lattice` solution:

```
library("lattice")
C <- read.csv('Collie 3.csv')

bwplot(TN.TP~ Site| Seasonal.Flow,data=C,main="Collie River TN:TP",
   ylab="ratio",xlab="Site + Flow regime", horizontal=FALSE, 
   groups = Land.Use, auto.key=TRUE,
   panel = panel.superpose,
   panel.groups = panel.bwplot)
```

Using `layout()`allows you to specify the number of columns and rows:

```
bwplot(TN.TP~ Site| Seasonal.Flow,data=C,main="Collie River TN:TP",
   ylab="ratio",xlab="Site + Flow regime", horizontal=FALSE, 
   groups = Land.Use, auto.key=TRUE,
   panel = panel.superpose,
   panel.groups = panel.bwplot,
   layout = c(1,2))  # same layout as ggplot2 graph
```

Or, if you like to plot them truly separated, try something like this:
(look the third factor is added to the "formula")

```
bwplot(TN.TP~ Site| Seasonal.Flow * Land.Use ,data=C,
main="Collie River TN:TP", ylab="ratio",xlab="Site + Flow regime",
horizontal=FALSE)
```